# Django data was not brought to heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have Django apps, which include users and posts models. The apps work perfectly at local following making migrations and migrating. I tried two different ways to deploy the apps to Heroku. First, using Heroku Git, the apps works on Heroku the same as at local.

When using GitHub, however, all data were not brought to Heroku. I tried to run "python manage.py makemigrations" and "python manage.py migrate" on Heroku, but the data from local was not brought still.

I would really appreciate it if you could please explain and help with the issue using GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to migrate on Heroku as well, try:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

See the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python?singlepage=true)

Comment: I should disregard my answer anyway, from what I understand, whatever data you have created locally will not be available on Heroku as you have started a new database. What this does is just create your tables on Heroku, you'd have to re-create that data on the actual website for it to appear on your site. Maybe there's a way to do what you're asking, but I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: I created a few fake accounts on my website locally and pushed to Heroku and had to re-create them after I pushed as well. Just basically working with two different databases, local and Heroku.

Comment: I am fine with deploying using Git Heroku. I just tried using GitHub for convenience each time committing my codes to GitHub, which are then automatically deployed to Heroku. I was just wondering there was any code needed in Profile or extra file that help to migrate all the local data to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

check your .gitignore file maybe db.sqlite in gitignore file and you can remove it
another option is dumpdata and load in production
you can run

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```

and load data in production

```
python3 manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Comment: I do not use gitignore